# MS Access – Filtering #Multiple Criteria while Ignoring Null Values

Tags: vba, ms-access, filter

Essentially, I’m trying to filter a form on three conditions.. without one filter overwriting the previous..

1. Is the non conformance open or closed – **Source = option buttons**
2. Between a date range – **Source = text input field**
3. Which operations are involved **Source = Combobox**

I decided to use If statements to cover the options buttons. If option xx true then
The filters work fine until there is a blank value in either in the combobox or the date input text field..
*Then an error is returned saying Extra) in query expression*

```
If Me.Option54 = True Then
    Filter = "([Date] Between #" & Format([TxtDtStrt], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format([TxtDtEnd], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#) And ([OpDescription]=" & ([Combo58]) & ")And ([NCR Clsd?]=False)"
    End If
    If Me.Option56 = True Then
    Filter = "([Date] Between #" & Format([TxtDtStrt], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format([TxtDtEnd], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#) And ([OpDescription]=" & ([Combo58]) & ")And ([NCR Clsd?]=True)"
    End If
    If Me.Option54 = False And Me.Option56 = False Then
    Filter = "([Date] Between #" & Format([TxtDtStrt], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format([TxtDtEnd], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#) And ([OpDescription]=" & ([Combo58]) & ")"
    End If

Me.FilterOn = True
```

Is there a way of ignoring the filter if the source field is blank?

*I can’t seem to get the IsNull command to actually do anything*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end solution I found was to use IsNull and Not IsNull as Boolean combined with IF And Covering all the possible combinations in a public sub

Then call up the public sub on click of each of the filters.. Its working, just wondering if there's a more elegant way of doing it...

```
Public Sub NCRDtFltr()
If IsNull(Me.Combo58.Value) And Me.Option54 = True Then
    Filter = "([Date] Between #" & Format([TxtDtStrt], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format([TxtDtEnd], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#) And ([NCR Clsd?]=False)"
End If
If IsNull(Me.Combo58.Value) And Me.Option56 = True Then
    Filter = "([Date] Between #" & Format([TxtDtStrt], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format([TxtDtEnd], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#) And ([NCR Clsd?]=True)"
End If
If IsNull(Me.Combo58.Value) And Me.Option54 = False And Me.Option56 = False Then
    Filter = "[Date] Between #" & Format([TxtDtStrt], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format([TxtDtEnd], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
End If

If Not IsNull(Me.Combo58.Value) And Me.Option54 = True Then
    Filter = "([Date] Between #" & Format([TxtDtStrt], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format([TxtDtEnd], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#) And ([OpDescription]=" & ([Combo58]) & ")And ([NCR Clsd?]=False)"
End If
If Not IsNull(Me.Combo58.Value) And Me.Option56 = True Then
    Filter = "([Date] Between #" & Format([TxtDtStrt], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format([TxtDtEnd], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#) And ([OpDescription]=" & ([Combo58]) & ")And ([NCR Clsd?]=True)"
    End If
If Not IsNull(Me.Combo58.Value) And Me.Option54 = False And Me.Option56 = False Then
    Filter = "([Date] Between #" & Format([TxtDtStrt], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format([TxtDtEnd], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#) And ([OpDescription]=" & ([Combo58]) & ")"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Either have more conditional statements to not use filter if criteria is not provided or handle null to substitute with another value.

`Nz([Date], #1/1/1900#)`

`Format(Nz([TxtDtStrt], #1/1/1900#))`

`Format(Nz([TxtDtEnd], #12/31/2099#))`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time tom look at this for me, then end solution I found was to use IsNull and Not IsNull as Boolean combined with IF And Covering all the possible combinations in a public sub. Its working but doesn't seem the most elegant of approaches.

Comment: Could mark my or your answer as accepted to help other readers.